# In the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL / Bash on Ubuntu on Windows) how do I reset the colors to the default/original scheme?

Tags: windows, bash, configuration, color-scheme, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I somehow messed up my color scheme in my Bash terminal on Windows and while I know how to customize the colors in Linux (edit your bashrc), I really don't want to have to manually do this and select all the colors myself. I liked the default color scheme and just want that back. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Try this https://github.com/Microsoft/console/tree/master/tools/ColorTool

Answer (score 0):

.bashrc usually configuring the prompt and it's colors using PS1 (e.g. `idan@pc-name:\mnt\c$`). Where the default value on my WSL is:

```
 PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

With some mechanism to handle different kinds of terminals.

If you talk about the fonts and the colors of the background/foreground it is configured by the properties of the "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows" executable, right click on the ubuntu icon on the top left corner => Properties.